# How can I have multiple divs ( that are the same ) be "position: sticky" without overlapping each other with css

Tags: css

I'm trying to use sticky to have the div "Sticky" stick to the top of the screen, while allowing for transparency in the background, so they can't just overlap each other. I've seen some videos and tutorials on people getting it to work. but I can't seem to figure it out.

I've read that positions other than relative breaks it. but I don't believe thats used here.

I can't nest it, like i've seen in other posts, as i can't change the html. this is purely css for me.

This would be a good addition to my little project, but even being told its not possible with this html would save me hours of banging my head.

edit: I would like the previous 'Sticky' to move up and/or go away when the next 'Sticky' Appears.

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.Container {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden scroll;
  height: 200px;
}
.Wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.List {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}

.Sticky {
  height: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(200,70,70,.8);
}
.Message {
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.info {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.spacer {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Wrapper">
        <ol class="List">
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <div class="Sticky">
                <span class="Message">Sticky Box</span>
            </div>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <div class="Sticky">
                <span class="Message">Sticky Box</span>
            </div>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <div class="Sticky">
                <span class="Message">Sticky Box</span>
            </div>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <div class="spacer">Spacer<\div>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is a full-page container and you want different section titles to stick, I would recommend using Javascript to solve this problem - because you said you don't have control over the HTML.

Comment: that is seeming to be the only option so far. and if that is the case so be it, thanks for everyones time.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.Container {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden scroll;
  height: 200px;
}
.Wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.List {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}

.Sticky {
  height: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  background: rgba(200,70,70,.8);
}
.Stick1{top: 0;}
.Stick2{top: 20px;}
.Stick3{top: 40px;}
.Message {
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.info {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.spacer {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Wrapper">
        <ol class="List">
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <div class="Sticky Stick1">
                <span class="Message">Sticky Box</span>
            </div>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <div class="Sticky Stick2">
                <span class="Message">Sticky Box</span>
            </div>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <div class="Sticky Stick3">
                <span class="Message">Sticky Box</span>
            </div>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <li class="info">Info</li>
            <div class="spacer">Spacer<\div>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly, I don't have control over the html, and I don't want them to stack like that, I would like the previous 'Sticky' to move up / go away when the next 'Sticky' Appears.

Comment: @Mixter213 You might want to update your question and include that detail.

Comment: @Cully I've done so now, thanks for the clarification